# Using PyQGIS to remove overlap area between polygons of the same layer

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to create a plug-in to remove the overlap area between polygons of the same layer and I would like to do this by deleting from polygons (after subdivision of the boundaries) the polygons completely contained in others. To do this I use QgsGeometryEngine.contains but, for some reason, it never seems to have a positive response: the result is always a new layer with correctly segmented polygons but also overlapping ones.

```
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    polygons = [ feat.geometry().asWkt() for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

    shapely_polygons = [ loads(pol) for pol in polygons ]

    rings = [ LineString(pol.exterior.coords) for pol in shapely_polygons ]

    union = unary_union(rings)

    new_intersections = [ geom.wkt for geom in polygonize(union) ]

    epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

    uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

    mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'new_polygons','memory')

    prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

    feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(new_intersections)) ]
    feats_2 = []
    noAdd = []
    
    for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
        feat.setAttributes([i])
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(new_intersections[i]))

    for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
      polygon_geometry_engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(feat.geometry().constGet())
      for ii, feat_2 in enumerate(feats):
       if i != ii and polygon_geometry_engine.contains(feat_2.geometry().constGet()):
        noAdd.append(ii)

    for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
     if i not in noAdd:
      feats_2.append(feat)
    
    prov.addFeatures(feats_2)

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

The code divides well the polygons that overlap but it seems that "polygon_geometry_engine.contains" does not work: the result I get is always all the polygons

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question! I really like your approach to the problem but unfortunately your logic is flawed. Here is why:

- within the two for loops you are checking for intersections in the set of polygons you created by *polygonize*. All of those polygon geometries are only intersecting at their exterior borders, they will never be within each other. That's by design of the *polygonize* algorithm. Due to this your contains predicate always returns false.
- Secondly, i'm not too certain that `contains` is the geometric predicate you need at all. A geometry (A) contains another (B) if no points of B lie in the exterior of A (...) ([ref](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.contains)). I believe that condition is also violated when constructing your polygons rendering your approach useless.

I don't have a suggestion on how to 'fix' your script but I have a solution using shapely:

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize

layer = iface.activeLayer()

polygons = [ feat.geometry().asWkt() for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]
shapely_polygons = [ loads(pol) for pol in polygons ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()
uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'new_polygons','memory')
prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

# compare each polygon with every other one
# and remove the difference between both from the original polygon
for poly in shapely_polygons:
    final_diff = poly
    
    for poly2 in shapely_polygons:
        # skip evaluating same geometries
        if poly.equals(poly2):
            continue
            
        # handle cases where one polygon is within another
        if poly.within(poly2):
            final_diff = None
            break
            
        diff = final_diff.difference(poly2)
        if not diff.is_empty:
            final_diff = diff
            
    if not final_diff:
        continue
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(final_diff.wkt))
    feats_2.append(feat)
    
prov.addFeatures(feats_2)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

running the code above on a random polygon layer:

[image: animation]

While writing this answer I realized that the script is also not a completely working example. E.g. when two polygons lie within another the overlapping portions are not correctly cut out. But anyway hopefully it will give you an idea on how to approach this issue :)